# How to provide an image below the action bar in android application

Tags: android

I am developing sample application using android studio. In that application I am using action bar and I need to put an image below the action bar. I tried but the line is showing the between action bar and image.
I achieved this 
[image]
but i need like this 
[image]
how to accomplish this task. 
please help me.

Thanks
Naresh

Comment: change action bar color and themes to match with the image color

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="required height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

try out this xml structure for your design and let me know if you got any problem in it

Comment: still same problem Faris.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the shadow add this to your app theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Linear Layout with horizontal orientation as a Fake ActionBar and put the three lines imageAsset, the actionBarLogo and the actionBarTittle, and apply a Hidden ActionBar style, and when the three lines button is clicked, just call the `threeLinesBtn.performClick()` idk is just an opinion.